# how to add 2 cell in phpexcel after looping

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi everyone i have the code like this

```
foreach ($pilihans as $value) {
    $azRange = range('C', 'Z'); 
    for ($i=0; $i < count($pilihans); $i++) {
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle($azRange[$i].'6')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle($azRange[$i].'6')->applyFromArray(array("font" => array( "bold" => true, "size" => 12)));
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle($azRange[$i].'6')->applyFromArray($styleArrayBorder);
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($azRange[$i].'6', $value['kuisoner_pilihan_teks']);
    }
}
```

i want too add 2 column after looping, but i don't know what the last column?
please help, thank's before, sorry for my english :)

Comment: Last column is `$azRange[$i]`

Comment: i get the last column, but how to add one column again? for example the result column C - G and last column is H. i want to add column H and I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your `for` loop, do:

```
$azRange = range('C', 'G'); 
for ($i=0; $i < count($pilihans); $i++) {
 ....
}

$azColumn = end($azRange);
$azColumn++;
var_dump($azColumn);
```

This will give you a value of `H` in `$azColumn`;

Doing

```
$azColumn++;
var_dump($azColumn);
```

again will give you `I`, etc